# Como dividir a instância de uma classe através de outrw

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, dicionário

Para ser mais preciso, ontem abri uma pergunta pedindo ajuda na criação de uma classe que agisse como criador de dicionários, e prontamente fui respondido, segue a classe: `

```
class tuplas:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras):
    self.keys = list(keys)
    self.palavras = list(palavras)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    index = self.keys.index(key)
    return self.palavras[index]

def to_dict(self):
    return {key: palavra for key, palavra in zip(self.keys, self.palavras)}

def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tabela Completa: <{self.to_dict()}>'
```

O que foi uma mão na roda, pois consegui adiantar bem o projeto, mas me deparei com outra dificuldade, preciso de uma classe que divida o dicionário que resultou da classe acima em diversas partes, de acordo com a informação passada pelo usuário "quantidadeP", segue o rascunho:

```
class pagina(tuplas):

def __init__(self, keys, palavras, quantidadeP):
    self.quantidadeP = quantidadeP

def __getitem__(self, key):
    index = self.keys.index(key)
    return self.palavras[index]

def quebra(self):
```

Comment: O que significa "dividir em diversas partes"? O que acontece se o usuário passar `keys` como uma sequência tamanho 10, e `quantidadeP=3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo básico capaz de dividir a lista de tuplas `livro` em uma lista de dicionários `páginas`, com a quantidade de chaves `quantidadeP`:

```
chaves = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']
valores = ['um','dois','tres','quatro','cinco','seis','sete','oito','nove','dez']

quantidadeP = 3

livro = list(zip(chaves, valores))

paginas = [dict(livro[i:i+quantidadeP]) for i in range(0, len(livro), quantidadeP)]

print(paginas)
```

Saída para `quantidadeP = 2`:

```
[
    {'one': 'um', 'two': 'dois'},
    {'three': 'tres', 'four': 'quatro'},
    {'five': 'cinco', 'six': 'seis'},
    {'seven': 'sete', 'eight': 'oito'},
    {'nine': 'nove', 'ten': 'dez'}
]
```

Saída para `quantidadeP = 3`:

```
[
    {'one': 'um', 'two': 'dois', 'three': 'tres'},
    {'four': 'quatro', 'five': 'cinco', 'six': 'seis'},
    {'seven': 'sete', 'eight': 'oito', 'nine': 'nove'},
    {'ten': 'dez'}
]
```

Saída para `quantidadeP = 5`:

```
[
    {'one': 'um', 'two': 'dois', 'three': 'tres', 'four': 'quatro', 'five': 'cinco'},
    {'six': 'seis', 'seven': 'sete', 'eight': 'oito', 'nine': 'nove', 'ten': 'dez'}
]
```

Encapsulando a sua ideia em uma classe:

```
class Livro:
    def __init__(self, chaves, valores, quantidade):
        aux = list(zip(chaves, valores))
        self.livro = dict(aux)
        self.paginas = [dict(aux[i:i+quantidade])
            for i in range(0, len(aux), quantidade)]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.livro[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Tabela Completa: <{self.livro}>'

    def get_pagina(self, n):
        return self.paginas[n]
```

Testando:

```
chaves = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']
valores = ['um','dois','tres','quatro','cinco','seis','sete','oito','nove','dez']

x = Livro(chaves, valores, 3)

print(x)
print(x['five'])
print(x.get_pagina(2))
```

Comment: Pois é, conhecia já essa saída, mas por exigência do professor, preciso implementar isso em uma classe, consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: @barrosfilho_: Feito!

Comment: Mestre, funcionou mais do que perfeitamente! Muito obg! Mas por motivos de aprendizagem, pode me fazer dois favores ? O primeiro seria comentar o código acima, por linha. E a segunda seria, mais uma dúvida. É plausível passar para a classe livro já o resultado da classe Tupla (aquela q está na pergunta), pois já cortaria meio caminho, ou dessa forma é melhor mesmo ?